# SQL grouping and counting, and try to avoid temporary and filesort

Tags: mysql, performance, database-performance

I have two tables with matches and users.

I'm trying to find the way to get the top countries playing matches, and I have this SQL:

```
select 
  distinct(user.country), 
  count(*) as counter 
from matches
  left join user on matches.user_id = user.id 
where 
  matches.`date` between '2014-01-01' and '2014-03-15' 
group by user.country 
order by counter DESC
limit 10
```

The problem is that I'm getting "Using where; Using temporary; Using file sort" and the sql takes about 8s in a m3.medium RDS Amazon server (not bad one!)

I have user.country indexed. Both tables are InnoDB.

Any ideas to improve it ?

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nick` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` char(2) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `country` (`country`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=254183 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `matches` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2593195 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

EXPLAIN gives:

```
+----+-------------+---------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type   | possible_keys   | key     | key_len | ref                        | rows    | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | matches | ALL    | date            | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                       | 2386708 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,country | PRIMARY | 4       | matches.user_id            |       1 | NULL                                         |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
```

**EDIT:** Changing to inner join:

```
+----+-------------+----------+-------+------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys                | key             | key_len | ref              | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user    | index | PRIMARY,country              | country         | 7       | NULL             | 234262 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | matches | ref   | user_id,date                 | user_id         | 5       | user.id          |      5 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please show your dable definition and the `EXPLAIN SELECT...`-output. My first guess would be missing index on `matches.user_id`, `user.id` and `matches.date`.

Comment: There you have ... I've tried even forcing the use of the index

Comment: Uhm... thats weird. When I recreate this on my test enviroment, `key` and `key_len` are not `NULL`. The `NULL` value possibly indicates that there was no key at all, and therefore no index. Try checking the table.

Comment: table checking is OK ... and the create command shows the key ! Anyway, although I force the index, it gives me a lot of time execution http://cl.ly/image/2r3H3d163G0b

Comment: Yeah, but your `EXPLAIN` doesn't, but it should show it. This basically means your whole table is scanned, and thus slowing down the query significantly. Sorry, I'm currently out of ideas.

Comment: I suggest to try `USE INDEX` (for `date` index). But that may not help since MySQL decided not to use it for first statement